# In VASP, which option is better for monolayer relaxation: ISIF=3 or ISIF=4?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, cell-optimization, monolayer

Since I have started working on ***monolayers*** I was using the `ISIF=3` tag for relaxation, this was after recompiling VASP with the modified "`constr_cell_relax.F`" file. There was no problem in relaxing pure materials, but with the doping of 4x4x1 supercells I don't get convergence in relaxation and the calculations are taking too too much time.
On the other hand my friend is using the tag `ISIF=4` and he is getting always converged results.

Now I am a little bit confused with which tag should be used, since I think that ***because of vacuum along the c axis there should be no relaxation along it***, so `ISIF=4` tag shouldn't be used. I want to know your opinions, especially if you have worked on relaxing doped monolayers.

Comment: The convergence problems may be related to ALGO and IBRION, rather than ISIF.

Comment: So which ones should be used for monolayers with vacuum along c axis?

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2022/geometry-optimization-for-n-layers-in-vasp/2023#2023. By the way, the ISIF=3 tag with recompiled VASP [ modified constr_cell_relax.F] is suitable for monolayer relaxation. Also this post: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2032/how-to-start-with-structural-defects-in-monolayer

Comment: Related: https://www.researchgate.net/post/In_VASP_what_is_the_best_ISIF_setting_for_geometry_relaxation @Jack do you think you'd be able to write an answer to this question? Also you wrote 3 comments in a row on 17 February (at 10:46, 10:48, 10:49). In the future, it's better to edit the first comment and add to it, rather than to write 3 separate comments!

Comment: @NikeDattani Thanks for your suggestions. Later I will post an answer.

Comment: @Jack any luck coming up with an answer. Also, I was able to edit your 3 comments into just 1.

Comment: @ChiKou were you able to figure out any of this? Is there any update you can give us?

Comment: Yes @NikeDattani, I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dealing with monolayers, I have found that using the `ISIF=4` tag is better and is less time-consuming. As mentioned in [Vaspwiki](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/ISIF), it allows the relaxation of both lattice constants and atomic coordinates with a fixed volume. However, what is important here is uncommenting the `FCELL(3,3)=SAVE` line in `constr_cell_relax.F` file and recompiling VASP. This trick prevents the relaxation along the z-direction, which is negligible in monolayers.